# my screen not move next screen on buttons click in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to move one screen to next and code for that but its not move on next screen on button click.what is the problem in this code.

i want to move one screen to next and code for that but its not move on next screen on button click.what is the problem in this code.

```
smsDisplayViewController.h

@interface smsDisplayViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{

UIButton *btncomment;

}

- (IBAction)btncomment:(id)sender;


@property(strong,nonatomic)UIButton *btncomment;

@end


smsDisplayViewController.m

@implementation smsDisplayViewController
@synthesize smsdisplay,Id,btncomment;

- (IBAction)btncomment:(id)sender
{
    CommentScreenViewController *viewController = [[CommentScreenViewController alloc]
                                                   initWithNibName:@"CommentScreenViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"btn press");
}

[btncomment addTarget:self action:@selector(btncomment:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

i want to move one screen to next and code for that but its not move on next screen on button click.
i want to move one screen to next and code for that but its not move on next screen on button click.

Comment: Have you verified that self.navigationController is not nil?

Comment: yes but its not work. same code i m implemented other screen and its work difference is that there i tapping cell  and here button

Comment: @ChetanGharat, does your console log the `@"btn press"` message?

Comment: no that also not showing me any message

Comment: Either self.navigationController is nil, viewController is nil or the btncomment method doesn't get invoked.

Comment: then what to do for that? please tell me

Comment: If the navigation controller is nil, embed the root view controller in a navigation controller (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shI0pSer8Ag). If the `viewController` (CommentScreenViewController) is nil, verify that the CommentScreenViewController.xib file is indeed copied to the app bundle. if `btncomment` is not invoked, move `[btncomment addTarget:self action:@selector(btncomment:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` to the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: If you are working with nib, storyboard or creating UIView programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t want to use NavigationController, then use the below code

```
- (IBAction)btncomment:(id)sender
{
   CommentScreenViewController *nextViewController = [[CommentScreenViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"CommentScreenViewController" bundle:nil]; 
   [self presentViewController:nextViewController animated: YES completion: nil];
}
```

Comment: sry its also not work its possible to move one nib file to another because i am doing that in this example

Comment: using navigation controller

Comment: Are you getting any error, when you click the button...?

Comment: So use this code exactly and reply ..its working or not...    UIButton *btncomment = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 100, 35)];
[btncomment setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btncomment addTarget:self action:@selector(btncomment) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  [self.view addSubView:btncomment];    -(void) btncomment
{CommentScreenViewController *nextViewController = [[CommentScreenViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"CommentScreenViewController" bundle:nil]; 
[self presentViewController:nextViewController animated: YES completion: nil];}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63926/discussion-between-teja-kumar-bethina-and-chetan-gharat).

Comment: no its not work sry but this code is correct but why this code not use in my project

Answer (score 0):

I think your *self* is not a navigationController, so the property

```
self.navigationController
```

Returns nil!

If you want, you can switch between controller without a navigation controller using the Storyboard or presenting new controllers modally:

```
UIViewController *newViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController: newViewController animated: YES completion: nil];
```

Comment: i am using nib file not storyboard

Comment: In the IBAction method did you present the controller modally as I told you?
However I think your btncomment method may be ever not called! Do you notice the log in the console?